# Differences in rails between new + save and create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm new to rails and I don't understand the differences between the use of new+save methods and the create method.

```
def create
    @item = Item.new(params[:item])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @item.save
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

and:

```
  def create

    respond_to do |format|
      if Item.create(params[:item])
        format.html { redirect_to @item, notice: 'Item was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @item, status: :created, location: @item }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @item.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Internally [`create`](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L40) calls `new` then `save` anyway:

```
  def create(attributes = nil, options = {}, &block)
    if attributes.is_a?(Array)
      attributes.collect { |attr| create(attr, options, &block) }
    else
      object = new(attributes, options, &block)
      object.save
      object
    end
  end
```

Comment: Brilliant! you cite the source code, so anybody can check and substantiate your claims.

Answer (score 143):

Although it is correct that `create` calls `new` and then `save` there is a big difference between the two alternatives in their return values.

`Save` returns either `true` or `false` depending on whether the object was saved successfully to the database or not. This can then be used for flow control as per the first example in the question above.

`Create` will return the model regardless of whether the object was saved or not. This has implications for the code above in that the top branch of the `if` statement will always be executed even if the object fails validations and is not saved.

If you use `create` with branching logic you are at risk of silent failures which is not the case if you use `new` + `save`.

The `create` alternative can be useful in controllers where `respond_with` is used for API (JSON/XML) responses. In this case the existence of errors on the object will cause the errors to be returned in the response with a status of `unprocessable_entity`, which is exactly what you want from an API.

I would always use the `new` + `save` option for html, especially if you are relying on the return value for flow control.

Comment: "If you use create with branching logic you are at risk of silent failures which is not the case if you use new + save."  Thanks for this!

Comment: For object validation and the create shorthand use: 
`.create(...).valid?`
It will return true and create the object or return false and do nothing.

Comment: Am I right in saying that it is better to `new` and `save` in modals? @nmott is that what you mean by HTML?

Answer (score 23):

`new` creates the object but doesn't save it.

`create` creates the object **and** saves it, i.e. `.new` and `.save`

`create!` creates the object and tries to save it but raises an exception if validations fails, e.g. `.new` and `.save!`

One of confusion items is that the above is the actions that you take on an object, but similar names are also given to controller methods, especially in a RESTful environment.  For example you have a create action.... which creates a new object, and then saves it and another create action which just does an object create.

If you're wondering "why create an object if I'm not going to save it?" consider this - the system 'tries' to save the object - but a validation prevents it and the user is asked to fill in more information on a form, perhaps required fields.  One wants the object to still be created (`.new`) while this is going on and it will hold the values that have been assigned so far.  However it doesn't actually get `save`d until it passes the validations as well.

Answer (score 5):

when you use, rails actually is creating the records but didn't save it, so in the process you can also assign smth

```
@item = Item.new(params[:item])
```

but when you use:

```
if Item.create(params[:item])
.....
```

it will immediately create and save

you can check it with `rails c`

Comment: ok but in my case there are differences between using new+save or only directly create?