# Cannot Define Attribute in Create method Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In rails 4.2.4, I can successfully execute this line of code.

```
Model.Create!(name: "Bob")
```

In Rails 4.2.5, this does nothing and leaves me with a null field in the database. To get past this, I must do something like this...

```
s = Model.Create!()
s.name = "Bob"
s.save!
```

Does anyone know why the first method doesn't work? Has rails been updated to something different? I haven't been able to find a solution for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is that the new standard for Rails 4.2.5? @uDaY

Comment: Can you give the app code that you see that happening?

Comment: the method is called `Model.create!` - notice that its downcase. This is the shorthand equivelent of `m = Model.new(name: "bob"); m.save!`.

Comment: According to Docs, nothing has changed that prevents passing in attributes hash. http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence/ClassMethods.html

Comment: I'm guessing that you are just doing something silly like a custom initializer without calling `super` or a custom setter. It does not match the behaviour as documented.

Comment: Good catch on the use of uppercase, I bet that's it. Developing on a windows machine?

Comment: `.Create!` would raise `undefined method Create!'` and not insert a row into the db. I'm guessing thats just a typo in the SO question caused by the browser trying to be helpful. We can only guess about what is really going wrong without more code.

Answer (score 0):

Difference Between `Model.create()` and `Model.new()`

`Model.create()` It will create and save empty columns DB, if its not "validated".

`Model.new()` It will create empty table but not saves it in DB. Until will not be saved.

Example:

```
 u = User.new
 u.first_name = 'Joe'
 u.last_name  = 'Doe'
 u.save #this saves DB.
```

Here is good [Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791386/differences-between-new-save-and-create)