# Need to genrate bills for all users in rails, what should be create method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, activeadmin

**Hi,**

*I need to generate bills for all users (residents) in my app, the bill_controller's `create` method looks like :*

```
    def create
    resident = Resident.find_by(hostel:current_admin_user.hostel) # current_admin_user  action is provided by Activeadmin to access current activeadmin user details 
      @bill=resident.bills.create(bill_params)
      if @bill.save
        flash[:info] = "Bills Generated  successfully"
        redirect_to new_bill_path
      else
        flash[:danger] = "Bills Not generated, Please try again!"
        redirect_to new_bill_path

      end
  end
```

> The active admin users can generate bills, and bills will be generated
>   only for residents that have same hostel with admin user ! And bills
>   should be generated for all residents with specific hostel. check out
>   my code, right now it is generating only for current user(resident
>   logged in) . thanks !

Comment: What is your question? Does your code raise an error? What is the error message?

Comment: actually it is generating only one bill which is of current user. I want it to generate bills for all users who have same hostel with admin. means `current_admin_hostel == resident.hostel` then generate bills only for  residents of that hostel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use where to get all residents for that hostel:

```
residents = Resident.where(hostel: Hostel.where(name: current_admin_user.hostel).first.id)
```

Loop through residents and create the bill for each resident :

```
residents.each do |resident|
  # Note here I use bill_params (because it's in your example), but I'm not totally sure it's the behavior you want
  resident.bills.create(bill_params)
end
```

Please note that you were using `create` so the `@bill.save` your were using is unnecessary (`create` calls `save` anyway, see [Differences between new + save and create](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9791386/differences-between-new-save-and-create)). To check if the bill has been successfully created you could use `@bill.persisted?` for instance (see : [Determine if ActiveRecord Object is New](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7842920/determine-if-activerecord-object-is-new-or-created)).

Comment: `undefined method `find_all_by' for #<Class:0x007f8d99eeb0c8>` error !

Comment: @Nischaynamdev I just replaced it by where, it should work now.

Comment: how to check if object is created or not ? I m getting error both in `@bill.save` and `@bill.persisted?`

Comment: I have no @bill in my code, so could you provide me your current code so that I see where the error comes from ?

Comment: ` def create
    residents = Resident.where(hostel: current_admin_user.hostel)
    residents.each do |resident|
      resident.bills.create(bill_params)
    end
    redirect_to new_bill_path
  end
`

Comment: all is working well if I change second line to this    
 `residents = Resident.all`
I guess problem is in `where(hostel: current_admin_user.hostel) ` !

Comment: @Nischaynamdev it might be handy if you could give me the content of the 'residents' variable, because if no bills are generated it is likely that it is looping on no records. So could you give me 'current_admin_user.hostel' value and 'residents' value please ?

Comment: see there is a attribute in resident table named "Hostel" and `current_admin_user.hostel` returns hostel of current admin user . 
so basically residents holds all instances of resident model whose hostel is equal to admin hsotel. I need to generate bills only for residents of that hostel!

Comment: @Nischaynamdev I undestand what you want to do ... But still, you have a problem here ! So to solve it we must investigate. Generally in those cases it's just that you have a value that is unexpected. For instance it might be that current_admin_user.hostel is nil or residents has no record. So what I'm asking is are we sure that current_admin_user.hostel has a value (use raise current_admin_user.hostel.inspect to be sure), then look if residents is indeed empty, and finally if residents is empty and current_admin_user.hostel is good then verify you have residents in your databse for that hoste

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114132/discussion-between-nischay-namdev-and-pholochtairze).